# how to use Angular2 ngrx storemodule reducer (initialState) inject service?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ngrx-store, angularjs-injector

```
const initialState = {
// service.get();
}
```

how to service inject reducer ? How to use service in reducer? 
no constructor no class!

```
export function personnelReducer(state = initialState, action: PersonnelActions.PersonnelActions) {
..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- leave reducers alone.
- fire action on effects init.
- effects call service.
- service gives back results.
- fire action to update state.